# update á partir do código de placa de um veículo

Tags: mysql

Tenho 4 tabelas, o problema é q seu eu tenho na tabela a cor branca e quero alterar a cor apenas de um carro que possui a cor branca, altera de todos os carros com a cor branca.

`update tb_veiculo v join tb_marca_veiculo ma
on v.cd_marca_veiculo=ma.cd_marca_veiculo join tb_modelo_veiculo m
on ma.cd_marca_veiculo=m.cd_marca_veiculo join tb_cor_veiculo c
on m.cd_cor_veiculo=c.cd_cor_veiculo
set m.cd_cor_veiculo='1'
where m.cd_cor_veiculo='0' and v.cd_placa_veiculo='BBB002';`

[image: MER]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso ocorre por que tu estás setando a cor em uma tabela que possui uma relacao com a tabela tb_modelo_veiculo.
Logo quando tu atualiza a tabela da cor, a tabela tb_modelo_veiculo, que possui uma fk para a tabela tb_cor_veiculo,
referencia esta cor para todos os modelos relacionados.
Para definir a cor de um veículo específico, tu terias que remodelar as tuas tabelas e colocar uma referencia
para a tabela tb_cor_veiculo na tabela tb_veiculo no lugar da tb_modelo_veiculo.
Assim tu poderia fazer o seguinte update:

```
UPDATE tb_veiculo v set v.cd_cor_veiculo = 1
where v.cd_placa_veiculo = 'BBB002';
```

Answer (score -1):

Na linha de `update` use a clausula `WHERE` para filtrar o que você está querendo. No caso, alterar somente a cor branca.